# CQConverter.exe for migration of data from CQ to TFS 2010

Tags: clearquest

I am not able to find CQConverter.exe for migration of data from CQ to TFS 2010 under Common7/IDE folder . Can I install it from somewhere ? Will it support Clear quest web client 7.0 and VS 2010 ? Also do we have any other tool other than CQConverter for the same ?

Thanks in advance,

Hitesh

Answer (score 0):

If you're migrating ClearQuest 7.x into TFS 2010, you want the [TFS Integration Platform](http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/), downloadable from CodePlex.